# ipcalc output and grep. Want to return only the binary output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a command using ipcalc that gives me this output. Is there a way using sed or awk to only show the binary value?

```
homer@deusexmachina ~/Documents $ ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | grep Address
Address:   192.168.1.2          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000010
```

So that the output looks like this:

11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000010

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `awk` to print the 3rd and 4th columns

```
 ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | awk '/Address/ {print $3,$4}'
```

you can use `sed`, but `awk` will be easier

```
ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | sed -n 's/Address: \+[^ ]\+ \+//p'
```

since you tagged `linux`, most probably your `sed` supports `-r`

```
ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | sed -r -n 's/Address: +[^ ]+ +//p'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about cut?

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | grep Address | cut -d " " -f14-
```

or awk:

```
$ ipcalc 192.168.1.2 | awk   '{ if ($1 == "Address:") { print $3 $4 }}'
```